# How to create hive external table with avro file on qubole?

Tags: hive, avro, qubole

Can someone point in the doc to create external table on qubole base on avro files?

```
CREATE TABLE my_table_name
 ROW FORMAT SERDE
 'org.apache.hadoop.hive.serde2.avro.AvroSerDe'
 STORED AS INPUTFORMAT
 'org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.io.avro.AvroContainerInputFormat'
 OUTPUTFORMAT
 'org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.io.avro.AvroContainerOutputFormat'
LOCATION 's3://my_avro_files/'
```

The following directory have a bunch of avro files

```
s3://my_avro_files/

s3://my_avro_files/file1.avro
s3://my_avro_files/file2.avro
s3://my_avro_files/file....avro
```

Answer (score 0):

I believe you need to provide the schema as well. Please see [here](https://docs.qubole.com/en/latest/user-guide/hive/hive-table-formats/avro.html) for details on how to extract it and specify in the create table statement.